# Google Maps (in .net) - Drawing another map on top of existing?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

I've got a 3 pane google map integration in our VB.net software. For the most part it works brilliantly. Today I'm trying to get these 3 seperate objects to paint different polygons depending on the lat/lngs they're sent for each day.

First map control works all of the time. 2nd and 3rd however are being troublesome. I've attempted to screenshot what's going on.

[image]

As you can see, the polys are being drawn, but for some reason an entirely new map is being drawn on top of my original. Obviously this isn't right. I've got code all over the place too:

Here's the JS initialize that is called upon DocumentComplete firing:

```
    function Initialize(zoomLevel,lat,lng,type, bCanEdit, bCanDrag){  
        //Get the type of map to start.
        //Need to convert the GoogleMapType enum
        //to an actual Google Map Type          
        var MapType;
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                MapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
                break;
            case 2:
                MapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
                break;
            case 3:
                MapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
                break;
            case 4:
                MapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
                break;
            default:
               MapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
        };

        //Create an instance of the map with the lat, lng, zoom, and
        //type passed in
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);   
        var myOptions = {zoom: zoomLevel,center: myLatlng,mapTypeId: MapType};
        var MarkerSize = new google.maps.Size(48,48);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);     
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', Map_Click);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', Map_MouseMove);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle',Map_Idle);

        overlayLayer = new Array();
        overlayCount = 0;

        driverRouteLayers = new Array();
        driverRouteCount = 0;

        canEdit = bCanEdit;
        canDrag = bCanDrag;
    }
```

The VB.net that invokes the script to draw the overlay areas:

```
Public Sub DrawAreaOverlays(ByVal area As DeliveryArea)
    Dim gc As New GComArray()

    For Each p As DeliveryAreaPoint In area.Points
        Dim ll As New GLatLong(p.Latitude, p.Longitude)
        gc.Add(ll)
    Next

    WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("DrawAreaOverlay", {gc, Utility.Pens.GetHexColor(area.Colour)})
End Sub
```

And the initial DocumentComplete hook-in in vb.net:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    'Initialize the google map with the initial settings.
    'The Initialize script function takes four parameters.
    'zoom, lat, lng, maptype.  Call the script passing the
    'parameters in.
    WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("Initialize", New Object() {InitialZoom, InitialLatitude, InitialLongitude, CInt(InitialMapType),
                                     allowEditing, allowDragging})
    RaiseEvent PopulateInitialRoutes()
End Sub
```

These are the only methods that are called to start with, the rest are just hooks into the javascript methods to display various things, but nothing is called (like this) prior to this point. And on this specific form, I'm only displaying, not allowing end-users to manipulate the data in any way.

The DrawAreaOverlay method (JS) is responsible for the poly drawing (please excuse the state of the code, I've been ripping it apart trying to figure this out!):

```
    function DrawAreaOverlay(area, col)
    {
        if(area.Count <= 0)
        {
            CreateNewArea(0, 0);
            return;
        }

        var coordsString = "";
        var areaCoords = [];
        overlayLayer[overlayCount] = new Array();

        for(var j=0; j<area.Count; j++)
        {
            areaCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(area.Item(j).lat, area.Item(j).lng));
        }

        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: areaCoords,
            strokeColor: '#'+col,
            strokOpacity: 0.35,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#'+col,
            fillOpacity: 0.25,
            geodesic: false,
            editable: canEdit,
            draggable: canDrag,
            map: map
        });     

        poly.getPaths().forEach(function(path, index){
            google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(){
                var arrayOfPoints = new Array();                
                arrayOfPoints = poly.getPath(); 

                coordsString = "";

                for(var i=0; i<arrayOfPoints.length; i++)
                {                                               
                    coordsString += poly.getPath().getAt(i).lat() + ", " + poly.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + "|";
                }

                window.external.AreaPointMoved(coordsString.substring(0, coordsString.length -1));
            });                             
        });

        // INSERTION OF NEW VERTICES ALONG THE POLYGON EDGES //
        poly.getPaths().forEach(function(path, index){
            google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function(){
                var arrayOfPoints = new Array();                
                arrayOfPoints = poly.getPath(); 

                coordsString = "";

                for(var i=0; i<arrayOfPoints.length; i++)
                {                                               
                    coordsString += poly.getPath().getAt(i).lat() + ", " + poly.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + "|";
                }

                window.external.AreaPointMoved(coordsString.substring(0, coordsString.length -1));
            });
        });         

        debugger;
        //if(map == null)
        //{
        //  makeMeANotNullMap(zoomLevel, latitude, longitude);
        //  overlayLayer[overlayCount] = new Array();
        //}
        poly.setMap(map);
        overlayLayer[overlayCount].push(poly);
        overlayCount++;
        //alert("I'll work now, but why?");
        //window.external.DoNothing();
    }
```

Now the **REALLY** weird part. If I uncomment the alert box in JS (the: I'll work now, but why? alert) each map renders wonderfully. So something clearly happens to the map once the alert box has been dismissed. It's this missing link I'm after. But I can't fathom it.

Without the alert box, interestingly, the 2nd and 3rd initialisations of the map controls, map is **sometimes** null. I know this, because I've setup VS to debug the script. So you can drag each one (vigorously) and get the attached image above outcome, where the poly has drawn, but you can't see it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't have a clue why this is happening.

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite embedded within our commercial software. What I can do is give you the Googlemaps script and the source code of the control itself which only uses (in it's simplest form) a collection of lat/lng's - And only incorporates the WebBrowser control. If that would help?

Comment: @LokiSinclair I have built something similar before using Chromium as an Excel add-on.  Is your app decoupled enough to run your HTML/JS/CSS standalone in IE?  If so, does it work properly in IE?  I did have a situation like this, and it was related to the embedded browser not doing a windows repaint with certain DOM events.  This sounds like your case because dismissing the alert dialog is likely triggering the paint.  I believe I forced the repaint by changing the innerHTML of some meaningless DOM element that was off-screen.

Comment: BTW - I highly recommend CEF [or maybe Awesomium] over the WebBrowser control for this type of work.  It fixes your app on a single browser version.  GMaps not surprisingly could be pushed much further with a Chromium engine over the IE engine.